# Linux to windows connection refused

Tags: linux, mono, quickfix

I'm sure my lack of linux knowledge is what's causing this problem. I created a program in C# which uses QuickFix to do various things. I need this program to run on linux so I created an ubuntu virtual machine and recompiled the program with mono. The application starts ok but can't connect to my simulated exchange running on a windows machine. The error log returns Connection failed: Connection refused.

Could it be that I haven't setup linux properly?

Thanks

Comment: "Connection refused" means that nobody is listening on the port you are connecting to. Make sure that you have the right ip and port.

Comment: Thanks Joni, I had the wrong ip address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if your VM can actually connect to that port (while the windows application is listening) with `telnet`:

```
telnet <ip> <port>
```

If `telnet` can't connect to the port, then you should probably check your VM network configuration, the interface configuration on ubuntu, and probably the firewall (both on windows and linux). Run `ifconfig` to see how your network is configured.

Comment: A firewall won't cause this problem.

Comment: Thanks emjay and EJP. you're telnet test highlighted that I had the wrong ip address. As EJP said in this instance my firewall wasn't the cause.